# How to implement a REST service with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to build a simple microservice with "Spring Boot" with IntelliJ IDE.

One method of this microservice should to accept in input a List and a Double Value.

So I'm building this code:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
public class ECGController {

    private double v1 = 0.01;
    private double v2 = 0.01;
    private int il = 0;
    private static final double step = 0.0025;

    @PostMapping("/clearF3A")
    public List<Double> clearF3A(ArrayList<Integer> RRin, Double CR){
        try{

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
```

In postman I'm try to execute this:

```
{  
   "RRin":[  
      834,
      490,
      878,
      807,
      517,
      849,
      816,
      520,
      632,
      488,
      701,
      536,
      675
   ],
   "CR":2.0
}
```

but if I try to execute this request, I can display this message error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.eresult.cleanECG.com.cleanECG.controller.ECGController.clearF3A(ECGController.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: What does line 36 correspond to?

Comment: you have not shown the code inside the controller method so we have to take a guess what is wrong there...

Comment: The problem is that the two variables are NULL

Comment: Are you using jackson - default json handler for spring boot ?

Comment: it's like he can't map the two variables from the JSON.
I don't know if i using jackson

Comment: My first guess is that the parameter should have been a single object, annotated with some `@RequestBody`. You are sending JSON so somehow you must use Jackson to transform it to an object.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is bad.

Instead of providing `ArrayList<Integer> RRin, Double CR` to `clearF3A` function, you should have one object that represents whole post body (whole JSON document). That is *the rule*. In your case, your passed object should have two parameters, one is `rrin` array, and second one should be `cr`. Also, that parameter should be annotated with `@RequestBody`

Roughly, this is what you need to have:

```
@PostMapping("/clearF3A")
public List<Double> clearF3A(@RequestBody ClearF3ARequest){
    ...
}

class ClearF3ARequest {
    private ArrayList<Integer> RRin;
    private Double CR;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new object to represent your JSON structure. For example:

```
public class EcgInput {

  @JsonProperty("RRin")
  private List<Integer> rrIn;

  @JsonProperty("CR")
  private Double cr;

//todo: add the getters and setters and methods like toString()

}
```

```
public class EcgOutput {

  @JsonProperty("output")
  private List<Double> output;

//todo: add the getters and setters and methods like toString()
}
```

Then in your controller change your method to something like:

```
@PostMapping("/clearF3A")
public ResponseEntity<EcgOutput> clearF3A(@RequestBody EcgInput ecgInput) {
   //todo: your logic
   EcgOutput output = new EcgOutput();
   //todo: put your result inside it

   return new ResponseEntity<>(output, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Jackson will translate JSON to those objects, and vice-versa for you.